# Graph Theory : bridges , blocks and articulation points

Tags: java

I found this Code which finds the bridges and articulation points in a given graph,I need to find the blocks in the graph too , how can I find blocks in a graph ?

-Bridge is an edge in an undirected connected graph if removing it disconnects the graph.

- Articulation point is a vertex in an undirected connected graph (or cut vertex) if removing it (and edges through it) disconnects the graph.
- Block is a maximal nonseperable subgraph

Here is the code :

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    class bridgesBlocksArt
    {
    private int V; // No. of vertices

    // Array of lists for Adjacency List Representation
    private LinkedList<Integer> adj[];
    int time = 0;
    static final int NIL = -1;

    // Constructor
    bridgesBlocksArt(int v)
    {
    V = v;
    adj = new LinkedList[v];
    for (int i=0; i<v; ++i)
        adj[i] = new LinkedList();
    }

    // Function to add an edge into the graph
    void addEdge(int v, int w)
    {
    adj[v].add(w); // Add w to v's list.
    adj[w].add(v); //Add v to w's list
    }

    // A recursive function that finds and prints bridges
    // using DFS traversal
    // u --> The vertex to be visited next
    // visited[] --> keeps tract of visited vertices
    // disc[] --> Stores discovery times of visited vertices
    // parent[] --> Stores parent vertices in DFS tree
    void bridgeUtil(int u, boolean visited[], int disc[],
                int low[], int parent[])
    {

    // Mark the current node as visited
    visited[u] = true;

    // Initialize discovery time and low value
    disc[u] = low[u] = ++time;

    // Go through all vertices aadjacent to this
    Iterator<Integer> i = adj[u].iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        int v = i.next(); // v is current adjacent of u

        // If v is not visited yet, then make it a child
        // of u in DFS tree and recur for it.
        // If v is not visited yet, then recur for it
        if (!visited[v])
        {
            parent[v] = u;
            bridgeUtil(v, visited, disc, low, parent);

            // Check if the subtree rooted with v has a
            // connection to one of the ancestors of u
            low[u] = Math.min(low[u], low[v]);

            // If the lowest vertex reachable from subtree
            // under v is below u in DFS tree, then u-v is
            // a bridge
            if (low[v] > disc[u])
                System.out.println(u+" "+v);
        }

        // Update low value of u for parent function calls.
        else if (v != parent[u])
            low[u] = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);
    }
    }


    // DFS based function to find all bridges. It uses recursive
    // function bridgeUtil()
    void bridge()
    {
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    boolean visited[] = new boolean[V];
    int disc[] = new int[V];
    int low[] = new int[V];
    int parent[] = new int[V];


    // Initialize parent and visited, and ap(articulation point)
    // arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        parent[i] = NIL;
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    // Call the recursive helper function to find Bridges
    // in DFS tree rooted with vertex 'i'
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (visited[i] == false)
            bridgeUtil(i, visited, disc, low, parent);
    }
    void APUtil(int u, boolean visited[], int disc[],
            int low[], int parent[], boolean ap[])
    {

    // Count of children in DFS Tree
    int children = 0;

    // Mark the current node as visited
    visited[u] = true;

    // Initialize discovery time and low value
    disc[u] = low[u] = ++time;

    // Go through all vertices aadjacent to this
    Iterator<Integer> i = adj[u].iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        int v = i.next();  // v is current adjacent of u

        // If v is not visited yet, then make it a child of u
        // in DFS tree and recur for it
        if (!visited[v])
        {
            children++;
            parent[v] = u;
            APUtil(v, visited, disc, low, parent, ap);

            // Check if the subtree rooted with v has a connection to
            // one of the ancestors of u
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], low[v]);

            // u is an articulation point in following cases

            // (1) u is root of DFS tree and has two or more chilren.
            if (parent[u] == NIL && children > 1)
                ap[u] = true;

            // (2) If u is not root and low value of one of its child
            // is more than discovery value of u.
            if (parent[u] != NIL && low[v] >= disc[u])
                ap[u] = true;
        }

        // Update low value of u for parent function calls.
        else if (v != parent[u])
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);
    }
    }
    void AP()
    {
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    boolean visited[] = new boolean[V];
    int disc[] = new int[V];
    int low[] = new int[V];
    int parent[] = new int[V];
    boolean ap[] = new boolean[V]; // To store articulation points

    // Initialize parent and visited, and ap(articulation point)
    // arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        parent[i] = NIL;
        visited[i] = false;
        ap[i] = false;
    }

    // Call the recursive helper function to find articulation
    // points in DFS tree rooted with vertex 'i'
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (visited[i] == false)
            APUtil(i, visited, disc, low, parent, ap);

    // Now ap[] contains articulation points, print them
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (ap[i] == true)
            System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    System.out.println("Bridges in first graph ");
    bridgesBlocksArt g1 = new bridgesBlocksArt(5);
    g1.addEdge(1, 0);
    g1.addEdge(0, 2);
    g1.addEdge(2, 1);
    g1.addEdge(0, 3);
    g1.addEdge(3, 4);
    g1.bridge();
    System.out.println("Articulation points in first graph ");
    g1.AP();
    System.out.println();

    }
    }
```